# Using atexit() to export a Pandas dataframe to CSV on app exit: atexit() is printing print statement once for each row in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, atexit

I am using Flask, Python, and Pandas to store the results of incoming HTTP requests into a pandas dataframe. I am using atexit() with the dataframe as a parameter so that when the app exits, I can export to CSV.

```
def onExitApp(dataframe):
    dataframe.to_csv('redacted.csv')
    print('App Exited')
```

I'm registering it like after the dataframe is created like so:

```
atexit.register(onExitApp, dataframe=df)
```

I have used this same code before in other apps and the print statement was only executed once when the app was exited. However, when I exit this app, I'm getting **App Exited** printed the console once for every row in the dataframe. I've been scouring for examples containing this issue but am not finding anything. Am I missing something obvious, or has anything changed in atexit that would result in this? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Is it possible you have `atexit.register` in a loop?

Comment: if you register it everytime when you create `dataframe` then you may registered many times with different dataframes. You could register it only once - at start without arguments - and this function could get DataFrame from some global variable.

Comment: I don't have it in a loop but I believe the second one might be the culprit! The dataframe is remade with an updated array each time a new http request comes in, so it does seem like it's being registered many times with different dataframes. 

I am struggling with how to make it work using a global variable for the data frame - would it be bad practice to instead move the creation of the data frame to onExitApp() so that it's only being created once at the end? @furas

Comment: Actually, I managed to make it work using your suggestion! 


`df = pd.DataFrame()`
`atexit.register(onExitApp, dataframe = df)`


I did this outside of the function instead of within and it is working correctly now. Thank you!!